# the string "php" is being printed at the top of my web app

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-4

This one is proving difficult to Google, so I thought I would ask here.

I have a Laravel 4.2 app that all of the output is prefaced with the string "php"

It is present in every view. If I do the following:

```
Route::get('test', function(){
    return 1;
}
```

Then in output, I get this:

> php 1

In my mind, this eliminates the string just being in a view file somewhere since no view file was used for that (someone please correct me if my assumption is incorrect).

I'm really at a loss here. This is showing up both locally and in production. I've tried using grep and regular expressions to locate the stray string, but I'm returning way too many results (as you can imagine).

Any suggestions on how to find and fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could try to search for `['"]php['"]` and `^['"]?php` to narrow the results down to what might actually be the culprit. Although to be honest, I suspect it's possibly something else. I hope you find the error.

Comment: So, it's likely in one of the files that's run on every request, like something in `start` or `config` or a helper, or something. When did it start happening? Can't you just simply step back through your version control and use that to figure out when it started happening, and therefore what caused it?

Comment: are your views part of a [blade template](http://laravel.com/docs/master/blade) or equivalent? e.g. your views have something like `@extends('master')`. If so, have you checked in those files (e.g. `master.blade.php`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Joel Hinz's regex to find the offending file:

```
^['"]?php
```

That brought up a file that started with this:

```
php ar<?php
```

So obviously, I started to type in "php artisan" while the cursor was still in the editor. Thanks to those who helped me figure this one out.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine one of the PHP tags doesn't have

```
<?
```

in front of it.